# Dynamic MX Records

Tags: email, dns, mx-record

I'm trying to figure out a solution to my problem which is as follows: There are two email addresses on my domain that I want to continue hosting at a provider but for all the other email addresses I want to host them on my own servers. Logically, I configure the MX records for pointing to the provider of my email hosting but in this case its like I want to maintain the current MX records for these two email addresses and then configure a new one for all others. Is there a way to do something like "check the destination email addresses and if its one of the following then reroute this mail to this mx record" or am I out of luck? I would imagine this problem has been addressed before.

Comment: Voting to migrate to serverfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this won't work via the MX records because the lookup is of the domain not the whole email address. You could however setup the new server to forward those accounts to a different email address.

Alternatively depending on your server make it act as a proxy for the old addresses, set a rule to open a new connection to the other server and deliver as if nothing has changed?